# Creating bundle to integrate into app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cocoapods

I am trying to create a bundle that has .storyboard, .xib , .swift and .xcdatamodeld files in it. The idea is that this bundle can be integrated into any app.(like a library)

So far i have tested with the views and swift files its working as expected, but i am not able to do that with the model file (.xcdatamodeld). I have tried to create this bundle with cocoapods unsuccessfully (Not able to create a managed object context).

So i decided to just copy paste the bundle source files into the app to make it work,but i am not able to do the same for .xcdatamodeld files. When i copy the code and paste .xcdatamodeld file into the app, i get the below error while trying to access a entity.

```
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'TABLE_TICKET' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'
```

Is there a workaround for this either using cocoapods or just copy pasting the source code or any other way to accomplish this ?